# Deploying Capistrano as user but need to chown directories to root:www-data?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy to a PHP project to a server.  I have a user on the server with sudo permissions (using sudo su), however I can not login in as root.  How can I make Capistrano change to sudo when logged in so that the folders and files can be chowned to 'root:www-data'?

The rest of the deployment is running fine, but the ownership is critical.  I have previously had root login so this has never been an issue before.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Simons solution :

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/07/capistrano-executing-a-command-as-root-without-using-sudo/